Как разделить flowFile на два?
Получаю из kafka json, из json необходимо извлечь параметры и сходить в БД чтобы взять некоторые данные, после получения данных из бд необходимо из полученного json извлечь массив и собрать в один flowfile. Получается что flowfile необходимо разделить на несколько и потом собрать в один.  Я правильно понимаю что без Redis или что-то подобного это не решить?
